# what are the Spring MVC Corresponding Components for Model, View, and Controller?

Tags: spring-mvc, struts2, spring-3

I'm new to spring 3. I studied several tutorials about springmvc, but I can't separately identify what are the corresponding components for model view and controller?
Like in struts2

- model-action class
- view-jsp
- controller - filterDispatcher
  Can anyone help me to identify these components clearly?

Comment: Not sure you understand a technology right. In spring mvc controller is a component which is not available to view, unlike struts components are controller delegates, that are available to view. You can treat it as models or actions or controllers, they are just POJOs.

Comment: @Dilis - This [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/) shows two out of the three components, and with a bunch more about configuration... View = jsp, just like Struts....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spring MVC, a Controller is usually a Plain java class annotated with [`@Controller`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.html), a View is anything that implements [`org.springframework.web.servlet.View`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/servlet/View.html) and the model is usually a [`ModelMap`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/ui/ModelMap.html), a specialized `Map` implementation.

In a standard setup, [a controller method usually returns either a String or a business object](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types).
If it returns a String, that is interpreted as a path to the view name (JSP, Freemarker etc.). If it is a business object [and the method is annotated with `@ResponseBody`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody), then [content negotiation starts](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multiple-representations), one of the key features of Spring MVC. Depending on configurable aspects like the Accept: header, the path extension etc. Spring automatically serializes the business object to JSON, XML, PDF etc.

The whole mechanism is explained in the Spring Reference under

> [**Spring MVC: Implementing Controllers**](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller)

Comment: @Dilis actually the model is usually a map, changed that, sorry

Comment: @Dilis The view is not necessarily a jsp. As Sean has stated, it can be anything that implements `View`. The implementation is responsible for doing something to the `HttpServletResponse` output stream.